# Extract traffic usage of an AWS Lambda using extension

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-extensions

I want to know the following metrics for each AWS Lambda function:

- number of invocations
- duration of each invocation
- how much traffic in and out the function has received and generated

The first two are easy to do. However, the last is more difficult to do.

Is it possible to use an AWS Lambda Extension to get the traffic statistics?

Comment: Is your lambda function deployed in a VPC?

Comment: No, it's not. It's publicly accessible.